# PayPal Payments Standard - Put multiple items in one form/Sell items without quantities

Tags: paypal

Web site will be selling memberships and guest passes for a swimming pool.  Two questions about PayPal Payments Standard:

1) I'm "selling" three different items, but there really is no quantity for any of them.  You either pay for one membership or none.  Is there a way to not allow a user to purchase (by clicking the add to cart button) multiple quantities of a given item?

2) Each of these items is in its own form tag, so I have 3 forms on my purchase page.  Is there a way to condense these 3 forms into 1 to make things hypothetically simpler?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1). Refer to https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Business-Archive/Can-you-remove-the-quantity-field-from-the-shopping-cart/td-p/652565 , there are some solutions.

2) You can combine these 3 forms into 1, but I believe you need to write some script to implement it or you can use dropdown option which buyer can choose item.

Hope these could be helpful.